# Button with two event functions. How to stop the second during the first function?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a "delete" button and on clicking cancel on the confirm box, it still submits the form. What is the best way to stop the form submitting given that these two event functions apply to the same button?

*The attribute data-confirm contains the confirm message.*

```
$(document).on('click', "[data-confirm]", 
     (function () { return confirm($(this).attr('data-confirm')); }));
$(document).on("click", "input[type='submit'], button", buttonSubmit);
```

Here is the function `buttonSubmit` with custom code ommitted.

```
var buttonSubmit = (function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Given a cancellation of confirm, how can i prevent `buttonSubmit` code from executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`e.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/Event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

Comment: @jfriend00: No, but I think it does.  (as long as they're both on the same parent)